# What do you say to your friends when you're about to sleep in the morning? What is the morning version of 'good night'?

Tags: greetings

'Good morning' is usually a salutation while 'good night' is said while parting for the night.

My question is basically "What do you say to your friends when you're about to sleep in the morning? What is the morning version of 'good night'?

Comment: If you're asking about what various times of day are called, it goes morning -> afternoon -> evening -> night.  Otherwise you might clarify what is meant by "open-greeting" and "end-greeting."

Comment: "Good night", said with irony.

Comment: The inferred meaning in the phrase "good night" is "sleep well". This should work, irrespective of time of day.

Comment: This same question occurred to me today because a friend at ELU was going to sleep and it was morning not night. You could edit the title of your question to make it more clear as in *what is the morning version of 'good night?'* I hope you don't mind if I do it myself, because I recently became eligible to edit other members' questions, and **I have now edited your question to make it very clear to readers,** because I wanted to learn how to do so! You can restore the original text and title if you like, by edit.

Comment: You can always say "I'm going to sleep."  Also "that's it for me."

Comment: *Good morning, good afternoon,* and *good evening* are salutations. *Good day* and *good night* are valedictions.

Comment: @flamesquirrel thank you for the kind edit -- I copied and pasted OP's explanation into the title but missed the error with *you're.*

Comment: My idea is to say good night in the language of a different country that is in a different time zone, in which it is already night time.

Answer (score 3):

Somebody has asked a very similar question here some time back and got many good answers:

[Alternatives to "Good Night" when sleeping in the afternoon](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68044/alternatives-to-good-night-when-sleeping-in-the-afternoon)

Considering the situation in **your** specific question,

(1) If **you** are going to sleep in the morning and your *friends are not*, then you would tell them to have a *good day* -- you could also say "I'm going to **hit the sack**" where HIT THE SACK means *go to sleep.*

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hit-the-sack

> It's time (for me) to hit the sack; you have a **good day**!

(2) If your **friends** were also going to sleep in the morning then you could very well use "good night" with the meaning of 'sleep well' as suggested in the earlier answer.

(3) **Consider "good morning"** which can be used not only as salutation but also as a *parting statement* as in "it was nice meeting with you but I must be off now, GOOD MORNING." This may be used even if you (or the other person) were actually going to sleep thereafter, though this information would not be expressed in that particular statement:

> "it was nice meeting with you but I must be off [to sleep] now; GOOD MORNING."

Pl. note that 'good morning' can legitimately be used in this sense but many prefer to say *good day.*

(4) Some parting statements that refer to sleep **without stating the time of day** (and thus ideal for your case) include the following common expressions already suggested in answers to that earlier question linked above:

> "sweet dreams",
>
> "sleep well" (also suggested by the member *flamesquirrel* in the earlier answer to this question)
>
> "sleep tight" and
>
> "pleasant dreams."

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think I would say, "have a good morning." When you say "good night" to someone, it's a farwell usually with the connotation that I hope you have a pleasant night and sleep well. I say "have a good morning" when I'm saying farwell to people around the early hours, even though it doesn't imply to sleep well since that's just typically not the time people go to sleep. I'm assuming what you mean by an "end-greeting" is some form of salutations, however I've never heard that term before, so I could be totally off.

Answer (score -1):

I’m on a graveyard shift and I would always say Goodmornight. According to [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=goodmornight):

> This word can be used just like "good morning, and goodnight" is used, though it is intended for us nocturnal folk that are always arguing on whether they should say good morning or goodnight after 12am, and before 5am.

Comment: Hi Daisy, this would benefit from a citation.  Neologisms are not encouraged, so I do hope you take the [tour] and see the [help] on how to answer.

Comment: Neologisms (words recently added to the lexis) are fine. It's non-words that are off-topic. References are essential for candidates in the grey area (this string appears on the internet, but has not made it into a major dictionary as far as I know).